# Улучшить прогноз с помощью регрессии

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, регрессия

Уважаемые коллеги, добрый день

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать.

Есть у меня прогноз продаж, который был построен на базе факта 01/01/2018/ - 01/11/2022 с использованием сезональности и скользящих средних.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе этот прогноз меня полностью устраивает, т.к. дает ошибку общую 12% , но возникла идея улучшить его с помощью регрессии.
Я знаю некие факторы, которые оказывают влияние на продажи: скидки, промо, цена.
Я знаю влияние этих факторов в прошлом (история продаж с 01/01/2018 - 01/11/2022 и факт факторов) и также у меня есть прогноз (1/11/2022-01/12/2023) и будущие факторы. Как подкорректировать прогноз с учетом влияния факторов в прошлом и зная будущие факторы?
т.е. не построить новое уравнение регрессии , а именно подкорректировать (возможно не совсем корректно выразился)

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что у вас входные данные:

- некие дополнительные факторы
- ваш прогноз продаж, построенный ранее

Целевая переменная:

- реальные продажи

Соответственно, вам просто нужно построить на этих данных новую регрессию.

Возможно, в качестве целевой переменной нужно использовать не сами реальные продажи, а разницу между реальными продажами и предсказанием.

Но в целом такая схема может работать хуже, чем если сразу использовать дополнительные факторы для предсказания продаж, а не так в два этапа как вы хотите.

Comment: т.е. прогноз использовать как регрессор и факт как регрессор?

Comment: @Сергей Да, как-то так. Получится что-то типа бустинга.